# How to run Channel first tflite model in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am able to run my custom tflite model in android but the output is totally wrong. I suspect it is due to my model needs input shape [1, 3, 640, 640] but the code makes channel last ByteBuffer. I have created tensor buffer like this `TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 3, 640, 640), DataType.FLOAT32)` but I still suspect inside the for loop, the channel is not properly set in the flat input (ByteBuffer).
I have copied this code from example where the required model shape was [1,32,32,3] (channel last). This is the reason for my doubt.
Below is my code:-

```
val model = YoloxPlate.newInstance(applicationContext)


        val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 3, 640, 640), DataType.FLOAT32)
        val input = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(640*640*3*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

        for (y in 0 until 640) {
            for (x in 0 until 640) {
                val px = bitmap.getPixel(x, y)

                // Get channel values from the pixel value.
                val r = Color.red(px)
                val g = Color.green(px)
                val b = Color.blue(px)

                // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement depends on the model.
                // For example, some models might require values to be normalized to the range
                // [0.0, 1.0] instead.
                val rf = r/ 1f
                val gf = g/ 1f
                val bf = b/ 1f

                input.putFloat(bf)
                input.putFloat(gf)
                input.putFloat(rf)
            }
        }
        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(input)
        val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
        val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
        val flvals = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
```

Comment: Propably for Pytorch models you have to do the bytebuffer customly. Check an example here where the float array is created for batch at the second position https://github.com/farmaker47/photos_with_depth#explore-the-code

Answer (score 0):

After using whiteboard and making and setting dim manually of the matrix, I figured it out.
It also used BGR instead of RGB as required by the model.
Working Perfectly now, here is the code (need to optimize multiple loop):-

```
    val model = YoloxPlate.newInstance(applicationContext)


    val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 3, 640, 640), DataType.FLOAT32)
    val input = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(640*640*3*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

    for (y in 0 until 640) {
        for (x in 0 until 640) {
            val px = bitmap.getPixel(x, y)
            val b = Color.blue(px)
            val bf = b/ 1f
            input.putFloat(bf)
        }
    }
    for (y in 0 until 640) {
        for (x in 0 until 640) {
            val px = bitmap.getPixel(x, y)
            val g = Color.green(px)
            val gf = g/ 1f
            input.putFloat(gf)
        }
    }
    for (y in 0 until 640) {
        for (x in 0 until 640) {
            val px = bitmap.getPixel(x, y)
            val r = Color.red(px)
            val rf = r/ 1f
            input.putFloat(rf)
        }
    }
    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(input)
    val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
    val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
    val flvals = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
```